# How to separate code into classes for swing jframe application

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm developing a Java application with Swing that has a JFrame with buttons and a JTable. It also reads and write files.

So far, I've created different classes for each input/output files.  DefaultTable model, Table and the class that does the user input validation.

My main class is still about 1000 lines. It includes the JFrame definition (buttons, fields labels etc) the table cell renders/ editors and the actual code.

This will be a stand alone application and none of the code will be reused or shared.

Should I worry about the size of my main class and try to move the frame and table code to their respective classes ? Or is the size of the main class acceptable.  What's the best practice in this case? Most of the examples I find are for very simple applications where everything is in the same class.

Thanks for any input 
[link to source code of main class](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B12iXW-1l_TVTlFDUDhtQlUzZXc)

Comment: Please send your code. It will be tricky to help you without it.

Comment: I've added a link to the original post

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely: Yes, you should reduce your Main class. Classes of 1000 lines are very large and will become hard to handle in further developement of your project. A good guideline for reducing your class is grouping code by responsibility. Here is a basic refactoring scheme i often use:

1. Try to find blocks of code that can be described to do a specific task/responsibility, for instance a couple lines of code that handle file input.
2. Isolate blocks of code for a specific task/responsibility in their own method for that task.
3. Finally, group together functions with responsibilities that relate to each other. Then create a new class that will become the handler or expert for this responsibility. Move the functions to their respective responsibility class.

In general, if you think of adding new code to an existing, first think "Can I create a class that does what I want my program to do?" instead of implementing it in an already existing class, method. If you find that the code fits nicely whithin the responsibility of a class you already have, you should implement it in that class, otherwise it can't do any harm to create a new class for the purpose of the code. For more information, read about Design Patterns, GRASP concepts and Refactoring.

Comment: I am COBOL programmer. I've taken java back in university but I don't have a lot of knowledge in OOP. But I was tasked to develop this app by my employer and took it as a challenge and a learning experience. There was no time for proper training. So this whole code may not be very inline with the OOP standards and best practices.